# Property not found on object of type "overLayerViewController *" Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C. It is a easy problem.

In `overLayerViewController` class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController* pickerRef;
```

In class A:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *picker;
...
overLayerViewController *overlay = [[overLayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"overLayerViewController" bundle:nil];
...
overlay.pickerRef = self.picker;
```

For this last line raise error:

> Property pickerRef not found on object of type "overLayerViewController *"

I click `pikerRef` is jumped into `overLayerViewController` class.

Comment: Which file (overLayerViewController.h or overLayerViewController.m) did you declare the `pickerRef` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In overLayerViewController.h file do this,

```
@interface overLayerViewController : YourParentClass

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController* pickerRef;

@end
```

Comment: Ohhh. I accidentally put @property into .m file. Thanks for point out.